# Read and parse JSON files with parallel processing

Tags: ios, swift

I have total around 6000 JSON files.

With the help of Codable protocol I am creating objects of the same.

Right now I am reading JSON files in for loop and it is taking around 30seconds to parse and creating object

```
var drugs = [Drug]()
let drugMonographURLs = [1.json,2.json,3.json]
try drugMonographURLs.forEach {
let data = try Data(contentsOf: $0)
    let drug = try JSONDecoder().decode(Drug.self, from: data)
    drugs.append(drug)
}
```

What is the best way to reduce the time here for parsing. i.e, read files parallely and construct objects.

Comment: Research Taskgroups

Comment: Best way is not to store that many models in your app, and not to parse them on every app invocation. Put them on the server and create an API that responds to queries instead (e.g. amazon lambda).

Comment: what is your target iOS version?

Comment: If the URLs are remote ones you are doing  the opposite at the moment: `Data(contentsOf:` works synchronously and blocks the thread. I agree with flanker: Swift Concurrency is state-of-the-art.

Comment: @hariszaman it is iOS 15

Comment: checkout async await more information here. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way is to do this

```
var drugs = [Drug]()
let drugMonographURLs = [URL(string: "1.json")!]
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
let group = DispatchGroup()
drugMonographURLs.forEach { item in
    group.enter()
    queue.async {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: item)
            let drug = try JSONDecoder().decode(Drug.self, from: data)
            drugs.append(drug)
            group.leave()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Done")
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as expected. Sometimes it used to throw exception saying malloc: double free for ptr
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: @user2523320 in my opinion i don't encourage you to such a way , re format how you use your data make them local or anything else , may be 6000 is too much

Comment: After parsing I am inserting into database here